# What does this hyper reference link lead to?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I am parsing a HTML file and I noticed that there is one element that reads:

```
<a id="someID" class="someClass" href="#" style="someStyle">
```

Can I please ask what this `href="#"` lead to?

Comment: Thank you for the code markup. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't go anywhere. This is a common placeholder for links that are implemented using Javascript. Another popular style is `href="javascript:void(0)"`; `void()` is a function that does nothing. Finally, the Javascript function that's run when you click on it could use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal action of following the link. But you should still put a placeholder in the `href`, so that when the user hovers over the link it won't show a target in the browser's status line.

Comment: It goes to the start of the document, when JavaScript is disabled. This is one of the reasons why the syntax should be avoided, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/138233#138233

Answer (score 1):

I generally use '#' to a trigger a JavaScript which works with CSS or page layout. In whole, its just a way to make a dead-link(not leading to any page) which you can use to call various webpage activites like JS or CSS.